# setter/ngOnChanges method of input variable of child component is called only once?

Tags: angular

`setter/ngOnChanges` method of input variable of child `component` is called only once?
ngOnChanges is giving console output only of the first time selectedRow triggers data. If the value of selectedRow change ngOnChanges if not triggering.

**Child chart component:**

```
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() chartData;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) { 
    console.log(changes);
  }

}
```

**Parent component html:**

```html
<app-chart [chartData]="chartData" ></app-chart>
```

**Parent component:**

```js
this.chartData = selectedRows // selected Rows are changed on selection
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: What is type of selectedRows?